# Calling a Function and using a file as a reference

Tags: c++, function, file

I am in a Beginning Programming course and have been having an issue with a program.

I need to create a program that should read a file of around 100,000 integers and determine whether or not they are prime or not. That part is not the issue, the issue I am having is getting the function to use the data from the file. Our CS lab is closed, and my professor doesn't answer emails so I don't have anywhere else to turn to. Thanks in advance for pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int p)
{
    bool result = true;
    int d = 2;
    int stop = sqrt(p);
    while (d <= stop)
    {
        if (p % d == 0)
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        else if (p % d != 0)
        {
            d++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{

    int count = 0, number;
    ifstream fin;
    string fileName;
    cout << "Input file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    fin.open(fileName.c_str());

    while (fin >> number)
    {
        isPrime(number);
        count++;
    }

    fin.close();

    cout << count;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having? What [debugging](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) have you done to isolate the problem?

Comment: Odds are what you have is working but taking an insanely long time. See if you can take advantage of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and a [Prime Number Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: @JaMiT I'm struggling to get the function to call and read the data from the file. I don't really recall what I've done in regards to debugging seeing as I've been trying to do that for the last 4 hours. I now only have the issue with the function call not wanting to use the data, and says there's no way for me to turn a string into an int. In its current state, once I input the file and have "0" outputted because of my initial count declaration.

Comment: Question: are you supposed to count the number of prime numbers? If so, consider something like `if (isPrime(number)) count++;`. That said, with 100000 numbers this is going to take a heck of a long time.

Comment: You might want to check if the file is actually open

Comment: @cmurray99 Sorry, that is still not a useful description. *(It's also difficult to parse. It might be time for a break.)* Perhaps if you could give a concrete result that you were expecting, along with the result you actually got? *The result of a fresh debugging attempt is just as good (better, in fact) than trying to remember details from the past 4 hours.*

Comment: In case it helps: an example of a useless problem description is _"I am having a problem with [result of personal analysis]."_ This is not helpful since it relies on your analysis, and that should not be trusted -- if your analysis was accurate, you likely could have fixed the problem on your own. An example of a useful problem description is _"My program is telling me that all 100,000 numbers are prime, but when I checked the file that was not the case."_ This is good because it provides a concrete symptom and allows us to perform our own analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand where is the problem. I have tested your source code, changing this line:

> isPrime(number);

for this one:

```
cout << number << ": " << std::boolalpha << isPrime(number) << endl;
```

and it works nice: [execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSBe7.png)

Comment: Unfortunately "Works for me." usually makes a poor answer. Assuming the file is open and it doesn't take hours to run through the 100,000 numbers in the file, the `count` variable looks like it is being used incorrectly.